# Adding currency symbol to tableview but remove on edit cell

Tags: javafx

I already know how I have to manipulate the table cell using a table cell factory callback. I added a currency symbol to the cell to make it look neat. (i.e. € 5,00 instead of 5,00) The thing is, when i double click on the cell i want that symbol to be removed. But for the heck of it, I'm unable to find how i am able to manipulate the textfield again to remove that currency symbol and bring it back in when the user committed the edit. Basically what I try to do is something similar when editing a cell in Excel :).

Any chance someone can help me out with a little basic example? Do I need to use the OnEditStart event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you want to configure how an item in a cell is displayed, without changing the actual data, you should use a custom `TableCell`. Here is an example that exhibits the behavior you want:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class CurrencyCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Double> {

    private final TextField textField ;

    private final NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private final DecimalFormat textFieldFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public CurrencyCell() {
        this.textField = new TextField();
        StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double object) {
                return object == null ? "" : textFieldFormat.format(object) ;
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                try {
                    return string.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : textFieldFormat.parse(string).doubleValue();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0.0 ;
                }
            }

        };
        UnaryOperator<Change> filter = (Change change) -> {
            String newText = change.getControlNewText() ;
            if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                return change ;
            }
            try {
                textFieldFormat.parse(newText);
                return change ;
            } catch (ParseException exc) {
                return null ;
            }
        };
        TextFormatter<Double> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<Double>(converter, 0.0, filter);
        textField.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);

        textField.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(converter.fromString(textField.getText())));
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
        });

        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        } else if (isEditing()) {
            textField.setText(item.toString());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        } else {
            setText(format.format(item));
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        textField.setText(textFieldFormat.format(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(format.format(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(Double newValue) {
        super.commitEdit(newValue);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
}
```

And here's an example using it:

```
import java.util.Locale ;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CurrencyCellTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        TableColumn<Item, Double> priceCol = column("Price", item -> item.priceProperty().asObject());
        table.getColumns().add(priceCol);

        priceCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new CurrencyCell<>());

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(10000)/100.0));
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(table, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public Item(String name, double price) {
            setName(name);
            setPrice(price);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
            return this.price;
        }


        public final double getPrice() {
            return this.priceProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setPrice(final double price) {
            this.priceProperty().set(price);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // for testing:
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("NL", "nl"));
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'm gonna dive in to it once I'm home. But by the looks of it, this is exactly the behavior I want.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. The great thing is, I already made a CurrencyCell class that extends from TableCell before I saw your post. But I just couldn't get it working. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: I got the think working. But there is just one minor problem. When I double click on the entry to make the textfield appear so i can start editing, the value is converted to a String. Thats good. But it forgets to format the double to a integer with two digit fractional number. (it currently has only 1, unless the second one isn't a zero). I tried to do a format in the filter myself but that didnt work out (the field even freezes). I want it to have 2 fractional digits. No more, no less :D

Comment: It doesn't convert the value to a string, it creates a string to display in the text field. Can't you just adjust that part of the code accordingly?

Comment: Yeah, I formulated that part wrong. I understand what is going on. I tried to adjust the string that is created to display in the text field. For instance with `textField.setText(String.format("%1.2f", getItem()));`. I put this inside the `startEdit()`. But then I get 0.0 in the textfield. That means it gets the default value.

Comment: The filter and converter I provided for the text formatter are not internationalized: you need to internationalize those appropriately. (Probably use a `DecimalFormat` and use `format` and `parse`, respectively.)

Comment: Updated with a (maybe approximate) version of that idea.

Comment: You rock. Again I was so close :P. Did you really look at my profile to determine the NL locale or was it a guess? :P

Comment: I checked the profile :). Had to set it to something to test it once I had internationalized that part of the code, figured it may as well be something helpful...